# Eliminate the Selected option if already selected in database...?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a select box with options up to 20, for example, if option 5 or any other is selected and saved in a database in the specific column it won't show next time...
please guide me

```
<select class="form-control text-center" name="code" id="Code"    >
        <option value="">Select Code</option>
        <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Ever heard of if condition ?

Comment: How to check the value if already selected from database?

Comment: are you asking/expecting for DB related code?

Comment: @M.Hemant yes like jquery and ajax....

Comment: share your db save code?

Comment: @M.Hemant  $this-> db-> insert('hr_levels',$data);

Comment: '$data['name'] = $this->input->post("name");
  $data['code'] = $this->input->post("code");
  $data['is_active'] = $this->input->post("active");
  $data['created_date'] = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
  $data['created_by'] = $_SESSION['username'];'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
function index(){
   //below code should be in Model this is only for example
   $this->db->select('code');
   $query = $this->db->get_where('hr_levels', array('created_by' => $_SESSION['username']));
   if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $code = $query->row('code');
   } else {
        $code = 0;
   }
   $option = array();
   for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++){
      if ($code != $i) {//no need to add if in view, just pass the data to view
         $option[$i] = $i;
      }
   }
   $data['options'] = $option;
   $this->load->view('option_view',$data);
}
```

view:

```
<select class="form-control text-center" name="code" id="Code"    >
    <option value="">Select Code</option>
     <?php foreach($options as $key => $value){ 
           <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
     <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
public function get_selected(){
    $this->load->model('model_name');
    $data['selected'] = $this->model_name->function_name($_SESSION['username']); 
    //Already saved values will be get on the basis of any condition

    return $this->load->view('file.php');
}
```

**Model**

```
public function function_name($username){
    return $this->db->get_where('table', ['created_by' => $username])->row()->value;
}
```

Now you get already selected value in `$selected`

```
<select class="form-control text-center" name="code" id="Code"    >
    <option value="">Select Code</option>
     <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++){ 
              if($i != $selected)?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
     <?php } } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: @UsamaHadi In the view, you will get the already selected value from DB. And I used the word "suppose"

Comment: Lets suppose first there was 10 options i selected any one and submitted the form it is now saved in database and page is refreshed. Now i want that on my next try it only shows 9 values eliminating the value selected  from last submission....

Comment: @UsamaHadi then you need to show us your table values and code using to store the record for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach it like this

```
$availableOption = range(1,20);
$selectedOrInDb  = [5,6,8,9]; // Selected OR from DB
$remaining = array_diff($availableOption, $selectedOrInDb);
```

Now you can use `$remaining` to loop through

```
<select class="form-control text-center" name="code" id="Code"    >
    <option value="">Select Code</option>
    <?php foreach($remaining as $key => $value){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Jhakar brother very helpful but how to check if the value is in database, if it is then it should not be listed in option....

Comment: @UsamaHadi fetch the records from db and push them in an array, https://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php